# В чем разница между HTML и XHTML в контексте Java

Tags: java, html, xhtml

К примеру у меня есть серверное приложение, которое запускается через `localhost`. Я java-проекте я могу создать `html` файл, так же создать `xhtml`. Также у меня есть `class MyClass`, который содержит `private String text`.
Моя цель: вывести, к примеру, в `<p>содержимое String</p>`.
Что для этого надо использовать?

Comment: `xhtml` основан на `xml` и имеет строгую запись тегов и аттрибутов, нежели `html`. Все элементы должны быть закрыты. Теги, которые не имеют закрывающего тега (например, `<img>` или `<br>`), должны иметь на конце `/` (например, `<br />`); [подробнее](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML)

Comment: Если выбор только между двумя форматами (html и xhtml) - то придется использовать второе. Для этого нужно знать JSF, Expression Language и про управление бинами. Вот простенький туториал http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-hello-world-example/

Comment: @Алексей Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, тебе нужно использовать сервлет JSP (очень грубо говоря html + java + js и xml с помощью jsf вроде так называется, ну тому подобное). В данное время, уверен, веб на java писать надо с помощью фреймворка Spring, который также использует во вьюхах jsp файлы. Но стоит помнить очень важное правило MVC программирования - вьюха не должно тянуть за собой много логики стоит дать эту роль контроллеру.

Comment: но это не решает проблему

Answer (score 0):

HTML и XHTML (оба языки разметки) это прост файлы которые организованы по каким то шаблонам. Тута без разницы что использовать для java все это одна и таже фигня